# How to undo setting Elasticsearch Index to readonly?

Tags: elasticsearch

So I just set one of my indices to readonly, and now want to delete it.

To set it to readonly:

```
PUT my_index/_settings
{ "index": { "index.blocks.read_only" : true } }
```

When I tried to delete it I got this response:

```
ClusterBlockException[blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/5/index read-only (api)];]
```

Then I tried to set the index to readonly false:

```
PUT my_index/_settings
{ "index": { "index.blocks.read_only" : false } }
```

But that gives the same error message as above. So how to set readonly back to false?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The correct way to make `es index` read-only is

```
PUT your_index/_settings
{
  "index": {
    "blocks.read_only": true
  }
}
```

change `true` to `false` to undo it.

You set non dynamic setting with

```
   {
      "index": {
        "blocks.read_only": false
      }
    }
```

which I think was not your intention. Also I think you should have seen an error during first operation itself as non dynamic settings can be updated only on `close indices`.

run

```
POST your_index/_close
```

and then try changing it.

Comment: Thanks, my issue was that I was using `index.blocks.read_only` instead of `blocks.read_only`.

Comment: @Kristofer answer is more up-to-date with current ES 6

Comment: As a one liner on local: `curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/_all/_settings" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{ "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete" : null } }'`

Answer (score 77):

Answers are really old so I'll add a elastic-6+ answer too:

```
PUT /[_all|<index-name>]/_settings
{
  "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/disk-allocator.html

FYI (for context): I ran into read-only indices due to running out of disk and got error messages from logstash:

```
...retrying failed action with response code: 403 ({"type"=>"cluster_block_exception", "reason"=>"blocked"
```

elasticsearch:
`ClusterBlockException[blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete` (api)];]

Comment: Correct for 6.4, curl command on localhost is something like: `curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/_all/_settings" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{ "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete" : false } }'`

Comment: Docs still say you should set it to null: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/disk-allocator.html

Comment: To apply this to all indeces, just leave out the "index-name/" prefix and send the PUT to "_settings" directly

Comment: Updated answer with _all suggestion from @Rich

Comment: Powershell: `Invoke-WebRequest -Met Put -ContentType application/json http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -Body (@{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete"=$null;}|ConvertTo-Json`

Answer (score 12):

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/_all/_settings" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{ "index.blocks.read_only" : false } }'
```

Answer (score 7):

In version 2.x of ElasticSearch (ES) you have to do the following

```
PUT your_index/_settings

{
  "index": {
    "blocks": {
      "write": "false",
      "read_only": "false"
    }
  }
}
```

While setting the index to `read_only` to true internally ES changes the `write` to true as well and just reverting `read_only` to false still does not allow you to update the index so you have to update `write` setting explicitly.

Answer (score 7):

If you have Kibana installed, you can go to your kibana url:

```
Management (Left pane) -> Elasticseach Index Management -> Select your Index -> Edit Settings
```

then update:

```
"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": "false"
```

Also, to set it globally on kibana you can go to dev tools (left pane) and make the following request:

```
PUT _settings
{
  "index": {
    "blocks": {
      "read_only_allow_delete": "false"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For 6.x to get the settings:

```
curl elasticsearch-sc:9200/_settings?pretty
```

To make the Indices / Cluster Writable :

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 http://elasticsearch-sc:9200/_all/_settings \
   -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'
```